# Appending parameters to a GET

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to pass 2 parameters to the following method.

```
<script>
                function messageKeyPress(field, event) {
                    var theCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode
                            : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
                    var message = $('#messageBox').val();
                    if (theCode == 13) {
                        var man =${manObject}
                        alert (manObject)
<g:remoteFunction action="submitMessage" params="\'message=\'+message" update="temp"/>
```

Controller

```
def submitMessage(String message,Man man) {}
```

According to the controller arguments, i require to pass 2 params. `message` and `man`. How can i edit the code so i could also send `man` as a parameter.

```
<g:remoteFunction action="submitMessage" params="\'message=\'+message I NEED TO SEND MAN OBJECT HERE" update="temp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tired this,

```
<script>
    var asd = "ttt";
    var aaa = "ppp";
    function sss() {
        <g:remoteFunction action="submitMessage" params="\'message=\'+asd + '&' +\'man=\'+aaa" update="temp"/>
    }
</script>
```

At gsp page:

```
<button id="asd" onclick="sss()">Count</button>
```

It gave me both parameter as expected.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple parameters on remote function like

```
params:'\'name=\'+FooBar+\'&address=\'+Earth'
```

At controller side,

```
def myMethod={
 println params.name
 println params.address
}
```